# Change MailStore from Gmail to Outlook on cloud

Tags: joomla

Civicrm/Joomla/AWS.

Just changed our email from GSuite to Outlook.

I see from Fetch Bounces error log "could not connect to mailstore @imap.gmail.com.

Where is the file to update this?

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#adding-an-incoming-email-account-for-processing-bounces-andor-email-to-activities. Go to admin - civimail - mail accounts.